# gVim ':terminal' accents don't work

Tags: gvim, terminal, shell

I am using gVim in Xubuntu 20.04. My version is vim 8.2.4295.

If I use a regular terminal, like xterm, and open Vim and then type ':terminal', I can use accents, e.g., íàê, etc. while in the vim-terminal.

However, if I try to do the same with gVim, the accents are never displayed. Instead of having íàê, I get iae.

Note that this only happens in the ':terminal' or ':shell'. For example, while in insert mode, both Vim and gVim behave in the same and expected way, e.g., I get íàê.

Is there any configuration that I am missing?

---

The output locale:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US:en
LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MONETARY=pt_PT.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
LC_PAPER=pt_PT.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=pt_PT.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

After many trial and errors I've figured out it works if `ibus` or `fcitx5` are used as input engine. I am using Xubuntu 20.04. Maybe in Ubuntu 20.04 the `ibus` is enabled by default, which makes it to work.

What is strange for me is that accents work in other gtk2 and gtk3, without any problem.

Some useful links:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/260601/understanding-setting-up-different-input-methods
- https://tedyin.com/posts/a-brief-intro-to-linux-input-method-framework/
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/1192517/im-launch-in-ubuntu-startup
- https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man8/im-config.8.html
- https://www.fcitx-im.org/wiki/Configure_(Ubuntu)/en
- https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/IBus
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49452/where-is-config-file-of-ibus-stored
- https://github.com/ibus/ibus/wiki/ReadMe
- https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Uim
- https://github.com/uim/uim/wiki/
- https://fcitx-im.org/wiki/Fcitx_5
- https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Fcitx5

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: My guess is that gvim's builtin terminal isn't capable of using or isn't configured to use UTF-8 or another encoding that supports the accents.

Comment: What's the output of the `locale` shell command? It seems to work for me in a recent Vim anyway in a quick test. Note that "Vim 8.2" spans a 2.5 year time period, so it's important to also mention the patch number (for example 8.2.4897).

Comment: [Instructions to request account merging](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. Is there any solution for this annoying problem?